# Notification issues while using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller, nsnotifications

Hi I am using `reveal view Controller` in my App. Its working fine in all scenarios.The problem is while calling notification. I had 6 front view controllers in my `reveal view`. In all `view controllers` I declared a notification with same name. I called this notification from `SWrevealViewController.m` file. Now notification action called in all view controllers. Actually notifications called only if view controllers in active state or it is in back of active view controllers.

Issue comes if I opened remaining view controllers at least once. If I didn't open them then notification not called in that view controller.

Comment: your question not clear I am not understand `Actually notifications called only if view controllers in active state or it is in back of active view controllers.

Issue comes if I opened remaining view controllers at least once. If I didn't open them then notification not called in that view controller`

Comment: Ok. In right side table I had jobs, cards, profile, addresses. If I select job , jobs view controller will revealed. I declared notification in all 4 view controllers.Once I revealed all four view controllers. Now finally I am in jobs screen. Now I called notification from Reveal view, then notification need fire in jobs view only. But it called all 4 views.@Anbu

Comment: simple, can you show your notification addobserver, postnotification and related code

Comment: show your code that how you declare notifications in all views!

Answer (score 0):

As you saying that you have declare notification with same name then you have to change it! otherwise it will get called in every viewcontroller.

For example you are adding notification in one view controller like,

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(notifyTouploadImage:)
                                             name:@"NotifyTouploadImage"
                                           object:nil];
```

here your notification's name is `NotifyTouploadImage` then you can not keep same name in another viewcontroller, in another viewcontroller you can change it like,

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(notifyTouploadImage:)
                                             name:@"NotifyTouploadImage2"
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: sry lion is not a good practice, if you are not remove the obeserver it will called multiple time, better we wait for questioner code, may be we optimze the same code

Comment: I am just explaining that notification's name must be different. One must remove observer! But here it is not main concern that's why i haven't mentioned! Because issue is with same name of notification! @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: If name is different in Reveal view controller number of lines increased while calling notifications.

Comment: i dont say your code openion is wrong, better we use different logic

Comment: @PhaniRaghu - can you show your code , its a single line of code solve your issue

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"revealControllerPanGestureAction" object:nil];  This is called in reveal view. @Anbu

Comment: @PhaniRaghu - show your addobserver and selector method as well as where you added the postNotificationName in yor SWL.m